# Can the Proxy class be used in AS3 on existing classes?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, data-binding, proxy

The AS3 `Proxy` class extends `Object` and exposes methods that you can override to handle the addition/removal and getting/setting of properties on the object in a universal fashion.

It appears that existing objects such as MovieClip, Sprite, etc. do not inherit from the Proxy class, so it would seem to preclude the possibility of adding such functionality to existing display object classes.

I've created a layout framework with a base display object class called `GUIControl` that inherits from `MovieClip`, and I was hoping to add data-binding functionality to it by overriding the Proxy class's [setProperty](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html#setProperty%28%29) method, so I could handle property assignments with a single handler to make all properties function as binding sources by default.

Is there some way to utilize the Proxy class's functionality on existing classes, or am I stuck building classes from scratch based on Proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You may create a wrapper class for MovieClip and set property on the wrapper. You should override other functions in Proxy and call the relative functions on MovieClip.

Here is an example

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Proxy;
import flash.utils.flash_proxy;

public class MovieClipWrapper extends Proxy
{
    public function MovieClipWrapper(target:MovieClip)
    {
        super();

        _target = target;
    }

    private var _target:MovieClip;

    override flash_proxy function setProperty(name:*, value:*):void
    {
        //set data on target movieClip, or call the notify functions
    }

}
```

Comment: That really doesn't solve the problem, because Proxy is still not being applied to the MovieClip instance.  This wrapper cannot be added to the display list, and if the wrapped MovieClip is added to the display list, none of the methods or event handlers will pass through this wrapper, since it's completely detached from the inheritance chain.

Comment: You don't need to add the wrapper to the display list.The wrapper is used for transfering data. You may add a function in Wrapper to get the MovieClip if you want to use the movieclip.

Comment: I know I don't *need* to, I'm just saying the wrapper *can't* be added to the display list.  As a result, the actual display object will inevitably be manipulated by the display list in a way that is invisible to MovieClipWrapper, so logic that should run when a property is set, will not run.  In a layout framework for example, changing the width of a parent element will alter the width of docked child elements, and because this wrapper is not in the inheritance chain, it cannot detect property changes on the object its wrapping.  Also, you don't need Proxy to write a wrapper like this.

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot be used on existing classes.  The worst part is that rules out using Proxy on any display list classes.  There is no way to alter a property on a display list class and have the Proxy class intercept and handle the setting or getting of such a property value.  Proxy is useful only as a base class for new classes (ideally dynamic classes), where you want to intercept and run logic when properties are set/retreived/removed.

Futhermore, Proxy is useless for trying to wrap something like the Dictionary class, since Proxy's interface methods rely on QName and String-type keys exclusively, which makes it impossible to enumerate over, get, or set Dictionary values that use object instances as keys... something Dictionary supports unlike associative arrays or normal Objects.